# Are there any problems associated with using files with no extension on a server?

Tags: php, file-extension

I would like to use files with no extension on my server. The reason for this is so that I can use that filename as a variable name as well. Overall it just makes things far easier in the application I am making.

The file is only used as an include file in a PHP site and it works with no problem. So the question is... are there any discernible problems with having no extension or is this bad practice? Would there be any compatibility issues if I imported this site to another server?

EDIT: Closed as it is off topic. The reason for this is obviously because it is tagged as "file-extension" and I was referring to file extensions. Also it was tagged as PHP when in reality I was talking about PHP. My bad.

Downvoted through lack of research... here are a list of links on stackoverflow relating to problems with having no extension:

1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would not take this approach, if this is necessary for your application to revolve around this setup. there should be any major problems.

As Moov Tony said, permissions are filesystem based, not based on the actual extension.

I would monitor the http requests on the otherhand, just to makesure these files are not being naviated through the http:// address.

I believe their are some website rippers out there that might beable to extract such files. But no server sided scripting can be ripped using said website rippers.

So overall, yes. There  should not be any problems revolved around a solution like this. I personally would monitor the http requests to your website to detect whether these filenames are being navigated too manually.

---

On the other hand, you will need to re-configure your webserver to tell it what to do with such filenames. Typically, some webservers default to outputting the file contents if nothing is instructed.

Comment: It just comes up as a text file on the browser if it is called... so all the code is there to be seen. The thing is, I would not put any code on that could in any way compromise security (like linking to the database with all the username/ pw etc :P). I am getting the impression that maybe it is best if I use an extension but it is just annoying messing about with the name. The file name needs to match a variable name - I know how to solve it but it is just the messing about I didn't want to do.

Comment: If the includes output the contents of that file in plain text.. Credentials and sensitive data crucial for your website to function, such as database names, connection variables etc should not be included for obvious reasons

Answer (score 1):

You should not encounter any problems as a result of not having an extension on your file. In terms of being able to execute the file, the permissions are based on the filesystem, not the file extension.

Comment: do you think it will not give ( unable to open. wrong file format) in any cases?

Comment: Rebo - like I said it works fine as an include file. Seeing as this is part of a University project I wanted to be sure that I wasn't doing something bad.

Comment: no. in terms of formatting and binary vs. ASCII, etc all of that is totally independent of the file extension. The extension of the file has no relation to the files contents or the ability for other programs to use or properly read from the file. The only thing that could possibly be affected would be if you are using some type of GUI to browse for files, and the GUI is using a mask to filter out files that do not contain a specific extension.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. In order to determine what to do with the file, the web server typically looks at the extension. If it can't determine it there, it will typically just outputs the raw file.

Comment: OK - I see your point but the file is actually just an include file. I suppose it could just as well be a text file. I opened it up on the browser and it just outputs the code like a text file. I would not put anything on it that would compromise the security of the site either.

Comment: Well in that case, it is fine.